# Hide a Span title from a th scope tag

Tags: css

I have to hide part of a table, the cells are th tags and inside the th I have Span title. I been looking but I can't find any tip. I would like to hide one of the cells, in sort of just hiding one cell of the the entire table. Its possible to perform this with the CSS file?

This is how my css is made:

```
.GridHeaderStyle th{text-align:center;}
.GridMainSytle td, .GridHeaderStyle th
{    
border:thin solid #ffffff;  
*border:none;

}
```

As you can see the th and td are together and I can not really just specify the th in question. Google developper tools show me that the th tag is as

```
<th scope="col" widgth="10%">

<span title="column1">
```

I have tried the follow but it hide me all the cells and not the one in question.

```
.GridHeaderStyle th[scope=col]
{
display:none;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please elaborate your question with an example of your complete table HTML and a comment on the elements you'd like to hide? I'am not sure if you want to hide a certain element inside the th or if you are trying to hide certain columns of a table.

Comment: Can you create new class,  like .hidden { display: none !important;}  and add it to span?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below CSS code :

```
.GridHeaderStyle th span {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the markup, it's hard to know for sure, but it's likely based on the example that the `th[scope=col]` selector matches all of your header cells. Look at using the `nth-child` CSS selector to be more specific, but be aware that's a brittle solution. If your markup changes such that the header you wish to suppress is now in a different order, your rule will hide the wrong column.

If your use case allows it, you could hide the `span` rather than the column, and therefore address the element a bit more specifically. Try the rule:

```
th span[title=column1] {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have tried the code but It doesn't work

Comment: I realize that inside the th tag there's a <a href = "javascripts1"> and after the span title is included. I dont know if this change something

Comment: As previously suggested, post a more complete sample of your markup.

Comment: Hi, I can't really give any example of the html because the one that I can verify its when I inspect the elements from the table (the one that I want to hide) when I go to verify the file from where it comes from its gives me the css file, the code that I have posted in my question. the main page its a apsx page so its doesnt give me any html page

Comment: Well, if you're not able to copy source from the DOM inspector, I guess you'll have to keep fiddling with it until you find something that works.